# 80s(?) sci-fi where prisoners riot to open a giant door

Tags: story-identification, movie

In a large white room (prison/docking bay?), dozens of pale (mindless? cultish?) inmates wearing orange all desperately try to open some massive metal door (gate?). Guards kill or immobilized most, but somehow (they climbed on top of each other in a large pile to reach switch?) they open it, releasing something (alien?) that wipes out everyone. A survivor (female?) manages to hide from the big ominous whatever (you only see it’s shadow).

What was this movie called? And no, I don’t think it’s the *Something Is Out There* movie/series.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this?

Comment: When you say you don't think this is _Something Is Out There_, did you actually check to make sure? It's free to watch on YouTube, and there's a scene that's uncannily similar to what you've described here.

Comment: It seems you may've lost access to the account you used to post this question. If so, that means you can no longer edit this question, leave comments within this thread, or mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You can regain the ability to do all these things by clicking on [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merging your new account with the previous one.

Answer (score 4):

This is ***[Something Is Out There](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0096134/)*** (1988).

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Something_Is_Out_There):

> *Something Is Out There* is a 1988 American science fiction television miniseries that aired on NBC, and a weekly series that followed in the fall of 1988, which lasted from October to December 1988.

> Jack Breslin (Joseph Cortese) is a police officer investigating brutal murders in which organs have been removed from the victims. He learns that the crimes are being committed by a monstrous alien insectoid prisoner known as a xenomorph, possessing shape-shifting and physical possession abilities, who has escaped from an alien prison starship passing by the solar system, and he teams up with a beautiful medical officer from that ship, Ta'Ra (Maryam d'Abo), to track down the villain. Ta'Ra has assorted superhuman abilities, including telepathy and superhuman agility, which come in handy during the mission.

What matches:

- There's a large, rectangular room, which is lined with small prison cells for humans/humanoids on the longer sides, and has a very large pair of doors at the end, behind which lurks a dangerous alien creature.
- The creature can exert some type of mental influence on people outside its cell. It influences one of the prison guards into releasing several dozen prisoners, and those prisoners work together to open the doors keeping it contained. Other guards shoot some of the prisoners, but they fail to prevent the creature from being released.
- The creature gets loose, but is not clearly shown.
- In the aftermath of all this, one female staff member -- a medic -- appears to be the sole survivor, while everyone else in the room lies dead.

What doesn't match:

- The room is mostly grey/metallic, not white.
- The prisoners are dressed in white, not orange.

You can view the sequence in question beginning at around the 53:49 mark in the video below.